# Server 2012 freezing up while trying to do a clean install

Tags: boot, freeze, windows-server-2012

i have a server i am setting up and am trying to install server 2012 essentials on it. when using a CD it goes into the boot process and the windows logo appears on the screen and the white dots do two circles and then freezes.

i tried putting an iso on a usb and booting from it and it gets to the part where it asks for the language, i press next and it freezes.

what could i be doing wrong with this? almost all my other installations up to this point have been easy peezy, but this one has been giving me so much issue.

Motherboard: Asus Motherboard P9D-V

Comment: I had serious issues with onboard USB3 causing install lockups on one motherboard I had.  Not sure if that's your issue at all, but maybe disable it in BIOS and see if you can get past that part of the install.

Comment: well, i think i disabled as many USB options as i can in BIOS and now it goes to a solid blue screen (not of death) just a blank blue screen.